# Remove .NET Framework

Tags: .net, windows-10

1. Removing framework using tool[image: Removing framework using tool]
2. [Installing framework error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqAu3.png)

I've to remove the .NET Framework from my computer (Windows 10), for that I used a tool `dotnet_cleanup_tool.exe` from Microsoft. But after removing the .NET framework and restarting the PC, when I reinstall the .NET Framework using `net 4.6.1(NDP461-KB3102438-Web).exe`, I get an error saying -

> I can't install because its already installed.

Comment: One of the caveats in the introduction section of the tool itself says that - `This cleanup tool will not remove versions of the .NET Framework that are installed as a part of Windows.`. So essentially .Net framework 4.6 which comes by default with Windows 10 was never removed by the tool in first place so the error message you are seeing is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I quickly pulled up Windows features window from Control Panel where you can turn ON/OFF any Windows feature on the Windows 10 machine.

1. Press <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open Run prompt.
2. Type `appwiz.cpl` on the Run prompt and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. Now click <kbd>Turn Windows features on or off</kbd> in the left navigation pane.

I doubt that Windows 10 supports enabling or disabling of .NET Framework 4.6.x as it comes with default installation of the operating system (OS). It only supports enabling **.NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services** which is not enabled by default (Refer screenshot).

[image]

I believe you're out of luck if you are looking for some graceful and properly supported way of removing .NET framework in entirety from the OS.

Answer (score -1):

In Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features

On the left panel select > View installed updates

Can you find "Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102438)" in the list ?

This place is the right way to uninstall .Net Framework

You could also find help from this guide :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. There is no such update.

Comment: Uninstalling an *update* will not uninstall the *base product*.